# How to flush one entity without flushing another using Dcotrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

How can I flush only one entity without flushing other entities?

For example:
I have 2 objects BStatus and B. They are related by OneToOne relation. 
I want to do some work on B without saving it to DB but save the status of the work on BStatus so another process can read it.

```
class B {

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    public $i = 0;

    /**
     * @var BStatus
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="BStatus", inversedBy="b")
     */
    public $status;

    /**
     * B constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->status = new BStatus($this);
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->i++;
    }
}

class BStatus {
    /**
     * @var float
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     */
    public $progress = 0;

    // <UPDATED>
    /**
     * @var B
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="status")
     */
    public $progress = 0;
    // </UPDATED>

    /**
     * BStatus constructor.
     * @param B $b
     */
    public function __construct(B $b)
    {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}


$b = // Load from DB

$max = 100;

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    $num = $b->count();
    $b->getStatus()->setProgress(($num + 1) / $max);
    // Here I want to save the status
}

// Here I want to save $b
```

**Update**
BStatus have pointer to B.

**Update 2**

Tried to detach B, flush and merge B back.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    $num = $b->count();
    $status = $b->getStatus();
    $status->setProgress(($num + 1) / $max);

    $em->detach($b);
    $em->flush();
    $em->merge($b);
}
```

Got execption:

```
 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException' with message 'A new entity was found through the relationship BStatus#b' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: local. 
To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).'
```

Comment: Can you use destruct for that specific?

Comment: You don't have cascade={"persist"} association. Why simply persisting status won't work? E.g. $em->persist($b->getStatus());
With calling flush later.

Comment: Yes but when I call flush() all changes that made before are saved

Comment: @DeepKakkar What do you mean by destruct?

Comment: @nutrija Persisting does't save the data to DB until you flush. But when I flush all changes are saved...

Comment: Where/how do you call persist()?

Comment: @nutrija Assume that entities are already persisted. Now I am loading them from DB and want to change them.

Comment: Have you tried $em->flush($b)?  I am not sure how the semantics will work for related entities.  I suspect status will get updated anyways but it is worth a try.

Comment: @Cerad flush doesn't get any params: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#323-335

Comment: Docs must be out of sync.  Check the vendor code: class EntityManager ... public function flush($entity = null)

Comment: @Cerad You are right! Thank you!! Do you want to create answer I will mark it as the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$em->flush($b);
```

Will only flush the specified entity.  Does not look like the online documents show this feature but a peak at actual code shows it has been these since at least Doctrine 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can detach object from unit of work

```
$em->detach($instanceOfB)
```

Comment: I tried. Throws exception:
exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException' with message 'A new entity was found through the relationship BStatus#b' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: local. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist  this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).'

Comment: You are right. If I don't have pointer to B from BStatus it works. But I need to acces B from BStatus. Updated question.